# Project-specific override for Cargo

Tags: dependency-management, rust-cargo

I primarily want to use Debian's Rust packages, rather than fetching some random code from the wider Internet (I'm old-fashioned, I know, let's not get into that part). To this end, my `~/.cargo/config.toml` looks like

```
[net]
offline = true

[source]

[source.crates-io]
replace-with = "debian"

[source.debian]
directory = "/usr/share/cargo/registry"
```

This works great after I install the `librust-*-dev` packages that I desire. However, in some specific projects, I'd like to lift this rule and tell Cargo "hey, you can in fact go wild and get whatever you want from crates.io". According to [the Cargo book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html), a project-specific `/project/.cargo/config.toml` should take precedence over my user one. Assume this project-specific `.cargo/config.toml`:

```
[net]
offline = false

[source]

[source.crates-io]
```

I'm still not able to `cargo build` a project with dependencies from outside of my replacement source. If for example, I make a `Cargo.toml` that depends on `yew` (a randomly chosen crate that I know isn't available in my replacement source) I get

```
$ cargo build
error: no matching package found
searched package name: `yew`
```

What am I misunderstanding about Cargo's sources, replacement and per-project overrides?

Answer (score 2):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69915017) suggested by @blackgreen is one possible workaround for the underlying problem until issues [10045](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/10045) and [10057](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/10057) (or a combination thereof) are solved. Another, perhaps slightly less ugly, workaround follows below for those who need it.

---

I ended up working around the problem using [UnionFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS) (I guess the more modern [OverlayFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OverlayFS) should work well too).

I simply add

```
[source.crates-io]
replace-with = "union"

[source.union]
directory = "/home/gspr/.cargo-overlay/union-registry"
```

to my `~/.cargo/config.toml` and then do

```
unionfs -o ro /usr/share/cargo/registry:/home/gspr/.cargo-overlay/local-registry /home/gspr/.cargo-overlay/union-registry
```

Now `/home/gspr/.cargo-overlay/union-registry` reflects the union of `/usr/share/cargo/registry` and `/home/gspr/.cargo-overlay/local-registry`, with priority to the former in case of conflicts.

So what goes in `~/.cargo-overlay/local-registry`? Individual extra crates, in the same way as in Debian's `/usr/share/cargo/registry`. That is to say, directories named `cratename-version` as they are distributed by upstream – but with a single extra file, namely `.cargo-checksum.json` added to them. The content of that extra file can be extracted from the crates.io index as follows.

Suppose we have cloned the crates.io index into `~/.cargo-overlay/crates.io-index`, i.e.

```
git clone https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index.git ~/.cargo-overlay/crates.io-index
```

Then suppose we've extracted a crate `foo` at version `0.1.2` into `~/.cargo-overlay/local-registry/foo-0.1.2`. We can generate the missing `.cargo-checksum.json` like so:

```
cd ~/.cargo-overlay
index_file=$(find crates.io-index -type f -name foo)
cksum=$(jq -r "select(.name == \"foo\" and .vers == \"0.1.2\" ) | .cksum" ${index_file})
jo package="${cksum}" files="{}" > local-registry/foo-0.1.2/.cargo-checksum.json
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you are suffering from this issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/8687

You would like to *unset* a config key on a upper-level `config.toml` but this is not supported.

I've played a bit with the config, and the only way I got it to work was to overwrite in the project-local `config.toml` the properties that were set in the upper-level `config.toml`.

In your case your upper-level `config.toml` specifies `replace-with`, so you have to overwrite that. But you can't overwrite it with `crates-io`, which is the registry you want to use, because that is exactly the registry with the `replace-with` key.

So until the above issue gets acted upon, we have to, essentially, use a mirror, both in the config and as an actual registry to download from:

```
[net]
offline = false

[source]

[source.crates-io]
replace-with = "crates-io-mirror"

[source.crates-io-mirror]
registry = "https://gitlab.com/integer32llc/crates.io-index"
```

As we both tested, it seems it's not possible to reuse the normal crates.io registry url because that is already defined and will fail with:

> error: source crates-io-mirror defines source registry https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index, but that source is already defined by crates-io note: Sources are not allowed to be defined multiple times.

So instead the URL above is an actual mirror server of crates.io. Then you can run `cargo build` successfully in the local project.

Answer (score 0):

The recently released [Cargo 1.56](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#cargo-156-2021-10-21) adds a [feature](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/pull/9839) that should let one do what my question asks for: [patch tables](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/cargo/reference/config.html#patch) can now be specified in a project-specific `.cargo/config.toml`, which means that `[patch]` stanzas can now be introduced outside of `Cargo.toml`. That should do the trick! I haven't yet verified this, as I am stuck with an older Cargo for a little while still.